# Shopify Sidebar menu - Display collections item quantity

Tags: drop-down-menu, shopify, menuitem, shopify-template

In shopify, I'd like to display the quantity of products next to the collection name, in the sidebar menu

When I add:

> {{- link.title | escape -}}  {% if link.type == 'collection_link'
> %} ({{ link.object.all_products_count }}){% endif %}

-It displays all items count in the collection like this:

> Menswear (43)       +  New Arrivals (43)  +  Ready To Wear (43) +
> T-Shirts   Sweaters   Trousers

I would like it to display each collection item count, and also in the list that is not drop down:

> Menswear (43)       +  New Arrivals (13)  +  Ready To Wear (20) +
> T-Shirts (10)   Sweaters (5)   Trousers (5)

Would be lovely to get some help.

Comment: Can you able to share the full actual code, where you using the same?

Comment: It seems correct and should work, need to review other code as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is to be right, right? but the thing is that it displays the same total in every sub collection.

And now I also realised that if I have scheduled products, it counts them, even thou they have not been published yet. So this function seem to be too complicated for me to use.